# Applying Interior Color if Active Cell eqauls specific text - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to StackOverflow and VBA. I am an Expert with all aspects of Excel except writing code in VBA from scratch.

What I am trying to do is apply an color from the index to the interior of a cell if it contains a specific term. Here is what I have:

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()

Do Until ActiveCell = ""

If ActiveCell = "STAR DISTRICT" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
ElseIf ActiveCell = "STAR SCHOOL" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
ElseIf ActiveCell = "HIGH PERFORMING" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
ElseIf ActiveCell = "SUCCESSFUL" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 34
ElseIf ActiveCell = "ACADEMIC WATCH" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
ElseIf ActiveCell = "LOW PERFORMING" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
ElseIf ActiveCell = "AT RISK OF FAILING" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 18
ElseIf ActiveCell = "FAILING" Then
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else: ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

The options are:
Star District or School,
High Performing,
Successful,
Academic Watch,
Low Performing,
At Risk of Failing,
Failing

This code works for one column (except for the bottom two terms) but it will not work anywhere else in the worksheet. When I try it anywhere else, all of the Cells turn Black (or ColorIndex = 1) no matter what the cell contains.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Trenton

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use conditional formatting?

Comment: Conditional Formatting only has up to three conditions. As you can see, I have 8 conditions.

Comment: yes but they are mutually exclusive.  You could just add 8 conditional formats.

Comment: No, you can only add up to three conditional formats.

Comment: that hasn't been a limit since 2003.  If you're using 2003 or earlier you should tag it in the question.  Check this article on working around it http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-conditional-formatting-limit.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your input data in your Excel spreadsheet, it is hard to say exactly why this is true:

`This code works for one column (except for the bottom two terms) but it will not work anywhere else in the worksheet. When I try it anywhere else, all of the Cells turn Black (or ColorIndex = 1) no matter what the cell contains.`

However, String comparison by default in VBA is a binary comparison, meaning it will be case sensitive and you are comparing `ActiveCell` to various upper case strings.  If your Excel Spreadsheet contains anything but all upper case, all of the tests will fail.

You need to do one of 2 things.  First, you can add `Option Compare Text` to the top of your code sheet.  That will change all comparisons to `Text` instead of `Binary` comparisons.

Or you can wrap each `ActiveCell` in a `UCASE` function, that will capitalize any value in the active cell before performing the comparison:

```
If UCase(ActiveCell) = "STAR DISTRICT" Then
...
ElseIf UCase(ActiveCell) = "STAR SCHOOL" Then
...
...
...
End If
```

EDIT:

As you mentioned in your comments, the problem was trailing spaces in the cell values, the appropriate code fix is to wrap `ActiveCell` in a `Trim` function.  And you can nest functions inside of each other like:

```
If UCase(Trim(ActiveCell)) = "STAR DISTRICT" Then
...
ElseIf UCase(Trim(ActiveCell)) = "STAR SCHOOL" Then
...
...
...
End If
```

This would trim any trailing and leading spaces from the value in `ActiveCell` then make it upper case to compare to your flagged value.

Comment: @user1486326 - the code as you posted works for me exactly as I think you want.  The only potential issue I found was the Upper vs Lower Case.

Comment: @user1486326 the only other thing I can suggest is digging into your spreadsheet values a little more closely.  Make sure you don't have anything misspelled, and there are no leading and trailing spaces as they will also cause the check to fail.  Make use of the `Debug.Print` function and the intermediate window to see what `ActiveCell` contains while the code is running (this will slow down the code so don't use it for an entire column of data unless you are willing to wait).

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. The problem was that whoever entered the terms into the cells had left a space after all of the ones in one column and a space after two of the terms in the other column. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure at which range you want to apply this code. From what I see in your code you want VBA to apply this "formatting" on **ActiveCell** and then select another cell below and repeat the "conditional formatting" procedure and then select another cell (with `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` ) and so on until it stumbles upon the first empty cell.

For this, the code should basically work ( I have tried it) and changes the interior color index of the cell it processes" according to your condition. Since this macro applies on the cells in one column from the **ActiveCell** to the last non-empty cell I do not understand how  you intend to use it on two columns.

The reason why this macro turns any cell to ColorIndex of 1 could be only that it contains text which is not part of your "conditions list". Also bear in mind that UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE are different characters so the value in the cells will have to be exact upper/lower case match to words/strings in your code  or  you can enhance the code to transform all letters in word to UPPERCASE ( using `UCase` for example)

You can try this code which applies the formatting in question to every cell in the selected range:

```
Sub ConditionalInteriorColor()

Dim r As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim index As Integer
Dim word As String

    'Set the targeted range to be the selected range
Set r = Selection

For Each cell In r

    word = UCase(cell.Value)

    'Choose index
    Select Case word
        Case "STAR DISTRICT"
            index = 50
        Case "STAR SCHOOL"
            index = 50
        Case "HIGH PERFORMING"
             index = 43
        Case "SUCCESSFUL"
             index = 39
        Case "ACADEMIC WATCH"
            index = 38
        Case "LOW PERFORMING"
             index = 22
        Case "AT RISK OF FAILING"
            index = 20
        Case "FAILING"
            index = 3
        Case Else
            index = 3
    End Select
    'Color interior of cell
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = index

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wanting it to do one column and then end. I would then move it to the next column and run the macro, but it wouldn't work. I only want it to do two columns out an entire spreadsheet, and I want to be able to check it after each column. That's why I just have the code end at the bottom of the column.
All of the characters in the columns are Uppercase, and the only options for the column to have are included in the code.

Comment: If it colors your cells black then you know it works:) and the only problem is condition setting. So try it with UCase and it should work.I can not think of any other reason why such simple code wouldnt work (except for active cell being empty).

Comment: The problem was that whoever entered the terms into the cells had left a space after all of the ones in one column and a space after two of the terms in the other column. Problem Solved.